# Where does the "unsorted" order come from in Glob?

Tags: c, ubuntu, filesystems, glob

I've been reading [an implementation](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/89a9acea1f9d821a9805b3857bf4febbba08690d/win32/glob.c#L521) of `glob` and testing it with Ubuntu Bionic and Trusty.

At a high-level I test a pattern such as `/foo/*/bar` using the `GLOB_NOSORT` flag against two directories:

- `/foo/A/bar/`
- `/foo/3/bar/`

Yes, I know I use `NOSORT`, and I don't want *sorting*. However, the order is 100% repeatable:

Every time I run this on Trusty I get `A` before `3`, and every time I run this on Bionic I get `3` before `A`.

The behaviour described by the glob manual is:

> Do not sort the returned list. By default, the list is sorted alphabetically. This flag causes the files to be returned in the order they were found in the directory.

But, what IS the order they're found in the directory? Where does that "natural" order come from, why is it always repeatable, and why does it change between those two OS releases?

Comment: @Ctx I thought that at first too but both are `ext4`

Comment: @Ctx I mistakenly thought you meant they were using different filesystems. I'm still curious why the results I have above are repeatable over thousands of builds of the same setup. I know the design doesn't promise order, but there is a repeatable ordering. I'm curious why the ordering would change.

Comment: @Ctx that's fair and I'll accept that as an answer if you convert your comment over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural order is, what the filesystem layer returns from a call to `getdents()`. The directory indexes there are not sorted, but in some optimized data structure to look it up by *name*. So the order on enumerating can vary from one moment to the other, in theory.

Also with ext4 you cannot assume any particular order, not even that it is stable from call to call. It is *usually* stable, as long as nothing is written to it, but even that is not guaranteed.

The difference in the kernel version involves also large modifications to the ext4 codebase; I guess it will be hard (but not impossible) to spot the difference in the code somewhere, that is the cause for the difference in ordering you observe.